# Is the word "women's" a typo?

Tags: grammatical-number, apostrophe, grammatical-gender

My browser's spellcheck says it is, but I can't figure out why.

Is Firefox sexist?

Comment: I think it may actually be a typo, as I have just found a book called "Language and Woman's Place"  http://books.google.com/books?id=7-NdKhaWQfUC&lpg=PA70&ots=I_BIaHumMG&dq=English%20gender%20pronouns%20sexism%20Lakoff&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: Firefox also flags `children's`.  Those ageist bastards!  (It doesn't flag `ageist`.)

Comment: Don't always trust your grammar checker - it may be wrong and you may be right.  On the other hand, don't idly ignore its advice.

Comment: @Malvolio: Does it flag `bastards`? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. It is not (necessarily) a typo. The following examples are all perfectly acceptable uses (at least grammatically) of the possessive form of *women*.

> Women's rights
>
> Women's work
>
> Women's intuition
>
> Women's gossip

I am unable to answer your question about whether or not Firefox is sexist.

Comment: Agreed. At my church I remember seeing a sign that said "Women's" something or other. "Women's" may be out of context if it is not implying ownership?

Answer (score 5):

"Women's" is the plural possessive.  If you're referring to one woman you should say "(a) woman's" instead.